# Android KitKat shows black menu text color even after changing it to blue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have developed an application in which i have used customized action bar, which consist of menu text in **blue color**. I have tested the app on Galaxy S3, S4 and everything working fine. But when i test it on LG Nexus 5, the menu text in Action Bar appears to be Black in color. Any idea why is that happening? Do I have to do anything special for 4.4 (kitkat)?

My app theme looks something like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/greyActionBar</item>
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
  <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/actionBarMenuStyle</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">@null</item>  
</style>

 <style name="actionBarMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```